# Defined Var not echoing value jquery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, variables

Hi I am trying to get my php variables to echo in my js code. I know technically php doesnt work in js/jquery but I've searched for workarounds and they dont seem to be working as expected. This is what I have --

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var stR = "<?php echo $htitle ?>";
var seq = "<?php echo $sequence ?>";
var coM = "<?php echo $comment ?>";
mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data, stR) {
data["htitle-" + seq] = stR;
return data;
});
mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data) {
data["comment-seq"] = coM;
return data;
});
</script>
```

And this is what is printed --

```
 var stR = "testing comments";
var seq = "0";
var coM = "testing";    

mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data, stR) {data["htitle-" + seq] = stR;
return data;});

mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data) {data["comment-seq"] = coM;
return data;});
```

So the php echos correctly when defining the variables but when using them in my functions, nothing works. I tried different combination of things and still nothing.

Basically in my functions I need "coM, seq, and stR" to echo the values.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
This is my goal and what I mean by I need the values to echo. ---

> modify to add your custom meta field values.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data) {
data["hello"] = "world";
return data;
});
});
```

"Hello" -- My meta key
"World" -- The Value

```
data["hello"] = "world";
```

Where it says world, I am trying to have to output of the var(s) I created.

```
 var stR = "testing comments";
 data["htitle-" + seq] = testing comments;
```

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You don;t echo anything. Do a `console.log` or `alert`

Comment: I hope you understand what @u_mulder say. Php has and 'echo' to output the vars in javascript you need to do 'alert(stR)' and if you use FF with FireFox you can output the variable with console.log(stR)

Comment: @u_mulder please see my edits above

Comment: I dont understand why its not clear? The quote text maybe confused it, I will edit. Please check @trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code uses the values you provided, but there is no code that actually calls the callback functions you have defined.

I have taken your code and added some tests around it, so to show that the values are indeed available to the two functions:

```
// Initialise the array of functions.
// Probably this is done by a library you loaded,
// of which you have provided no information:
mrp_data_callbacks = [];

// --- Original code BEGIN ---
var stR = "testing comments";
var seq = "0";
var coM = "testing";    

mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data, stR) {data["htitle-" + seq] = stR;
return data;});

mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data) {data["comment-seq"] = coM;
return data;});
// --- Original code END ---

// Define data
var data = {};
// Call the above functions for testing the result:
mrp_data_callbacks.forEach( function(fun, index) {
    fun(index, data, stR);
});
// check if everything worked, and data has received 
// the expected properties. We use JSON.stringify to 
// have a complete view of the data object:
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

The *alert* at the end outputs this:

```
{"htitle-0":"testing comments","comment-seq":"testing"}
```

So, this proves the values provided by PHP are readily available in the functions, through the variables *stR, seq, coM*. But you need to actually call these functions to see anything happening in your data object.

NB: *console* does not refer to what you see in "view source" in your browser, but to the tool in which you can query information about the displayed web document.

## Edit

If you want the PHP values to be directly injected in the relevant Javascript functions, then you don't need the Javascript variables (*stR, seq, coM*), and you can do as follows in PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data) {
        data["<?php echo "htitle-" . $sequence ?>"] = "<?php echo $htitle ?>";
        return data;
    });

    mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data) {
        data["comment-seq"] = "<?php echo $comment ?>";
        return data;
    });
</script>
```

This will come to the browser as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data) {
        data["htitle-0"] = "testing comments";
        return data;
    });

    mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data) {
        data["comment-seq"] = "testing";
        return data;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying, and I know what the console is. So how can I get the var to echo in my functions as I have it?

Comment: What do you mean with *echo*? You want an alert (modal popup window), an output in the console, an HTML element on your page receiving the value (which)? And when you say "var", which variable do you mean? The data array? In which format? JSON? ... we really need more specifics.

Comment: BTW: I was doubting you understood the concept of console, because what you wrote in your question to appear in your console is not the kind of stuff that appears there, but constitutes the output of PHP, which is the HTML source of your web page (and not the console).

Comment: For the console part, are you referring to Developer Tools on chrome?

Comment: It is what you address when you run the code `console.log()` (or any other method of that object). It is supported in most browsers.

Comment: Please check my edit above, maybe that can clarify a little better.

Comment: Thank you, thats what I meant. Cant believe it was so simple, I thought I've already tried that, maybe I forgot the quotes last time. Thanks though.

Comment: Question, the php values are echoing but if they change do the values update in the script? I was told this - mixing PHP and JavaScript wont work (server side vs. client side). If htitle is updated, the values will not be updated. E.g. if htitle is "Hello" then the callback functions will always be:
mrp_data_callbacks.push( function(index, data) { 
data["World"] = "World"; 
return data; 
});
The callback function is supposed to populate the values of the fields on the form to submit in the AJAX request. So you should use JavaScript not PHP to get the updated values from the HTML form.

Comment: Indeed, if you have an HTML form that the user fills in, then those modified values are not known by PHP until the form is submitted. PHP is only doing something when is passed to the server, not while the user is scrolling through the web page, filling in text. So in that case you should use javascript. That is why I provided my first solution more based on Javascript. But you explicitly said you wanted the PHP variable expand inside the functions.

Comment: So how would i able to pass the values like what I was trying to achieve, but using javascript?

Comment: This comments section is not ideal for treating new questions. I suggest you ask a new question on StackOverflow, and you will get the attention again of people who are good in Javascript. Make sure to add the code you have tried with, and clearly explain what is not working as you want. Good luck.